# How do we observe that there exist a bijection principle in a problem of probability? Does bijection always exist in combinatorial probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

It is clear that bijection is all about showing one-one and onto mapping exist together and hence the cardinality of two sets are equal.This is a problem from olympiad that gives the hint to use Vandermone’s Identity and the bijection principle to solve this problem. It has been [solved with IEP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631843/what-is-the-probability-that-in-the-%ef%ac%81rst-7-draws-at-least-one-ball-of-each-colo) in this website early but my problem is related to the application of bijection.

> Consider an urn containing $5$ red, $5$ black, and $10$ white balls. If balls are drawn *without replacement* from the urn, calculate the probability that in the first $7$ draws, at least one ball of each color is drawn.

$\square$ **My problem** - I know the definition of bijection principle but I always get stuck when it comes to apply in probability problems. Still I am sharing, what I think about solving this problem.

$\bullet$ The total no. of ways of selecting $7$ balls out of $20$ balls is $\binom{5+5+10}{7}$

$\bullet$ The no of ways to have each of the three colors in the $7$ balls is $\binom{5}{x_1}\times \binom{5}{x_2}\times \binom{10}{x_3} \text{, where } x_1, x_2, x_3 \text { are the balls of three colors and } \ x_1+x_2+x_3=7$

$\bullet$ The no. of ways not to have each of the three color in the $7$ balls is $\binom{5}{0}\times \binom{5}{0}\times \binom{10}{7} + 2 [\binom{5}{1}\times \binom{5}{0}\times \binom{10}{6}]$

$\bullet$ So the probability of having at least each of three colors in the $7$ balls is $$1-\frac{\binom{5}{0}\times \binom{5}{0}\times \binom{10}{7} + 2 [\binom{5}{1}\times \binom{5}{0}\times \binom{10}{6}]}{\binom{5+5+10}{7}}$$

$\bigcirc$ **Bijection Principle** - If there is a bijection between two sets then they have the same number of elements. I guess here in the problem among total $8$ cases [$0$ to $7$] of selection, we have this one-one and onto mapping, where no. of selected balls remains same-

$$\begin {cases}\text{selected balls } 0  \to \text{remaining balls } 7 \\\text{selected balls } 1  \to \text{remaining balls } 6 \\\text{selected balls } 2  \to \text{remaining balls } 5 \\\text{selected balls } 3  \to \text{remaining balls } 4 \\\text{selected balls } 4  \to \text{remaining balls } 3 \\\text{selected balls } 5  \to \text{remaining balls } 2 \\\text{selected balls } 6  \to \text{remaining balls } 1 \\\text{selected balls } 7  \to \text{remaining balls } 0 \\ \end {cases}$$

$\square$ If my way of thinking is not correct could you kindly explain how should I apply bijection in probability.

$\square$ Does bijection always exist in probability problems?

Any help is valuable and highly appreciated.